# Bad display content charles (awt?)

Tags: java, awt, charles-proxy

I test Charles with arch linux and jdk8/jre

But there is some problem for display the content. Somebody have the same issue ?

[Charles screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuN98.png)

Comment: It looks like you were trying to monitor secured (https) requests, weren't you? Could you please attach a full screenshot from the Charles window?

Comment: your right thanks you :)

Comment: Ok, le'ts post it as correct answer, so other people will easily find the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to monitor secured (https) request, that's why you can't see nothing understandable.

In such that case you still can monitor those requests but you first have to make your web browser trust the CharlesProxy SSL certificate.

Check the documentation at: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/